# Unable to fix 4 buttons in Grid Layout

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I tried to add 4 buttons in Grid Layout. Equally Spaced, I used colum and row Weight, but still I am not able to align all equally spaced, I am getting the output like this. Mentioned below in the image.[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.rahulcomp24.gridlayoutdemo.MainActivity">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button4" />
</GridLayout>
```

I am using MinSdk version 19.

[image]

Comment: Your layout is working fine on my setup tested on min sdk 19

Comment: @rupesh_padhye with same code ?

Comment: Make layout_width="0dp" and layout_height="0dp" for all the buttons.

Comment: @Abdullah If I do that it shows only two button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the below xml as it is and run it you would see same equally space button.

**Note:** You have to run it on your device to see them filling all screen space equally

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:text="New Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:text="New Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:text="New Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:text="New Button" />
    </GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Its working perfectly here you do not have to change anything else just change the layout_gravity of button 3 and 4 only

Comment: I can't share the screenshot but it is showing for buttons two  button on first row as in my previous screenshot and two buttons instead of filling all space it takes only normal button height and all the space below it is empty.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying you want the same height of all 4 buttons which could be done by changing `layout_gravity` of button 3 and button 4.

Comment: I want all 4 buttons to fill all the space equally

Comment: Have you checked it??

Answer (score 0):

You can use two LinearLayouts instead, one for each row, and also replace the parent RelativeLayout with another LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want to do it using Grid Layout. What is the mistake in the my Grid Layout Code ?

Comment: I copied your code in my own IDE and the preview was fine, didn't see any problem

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this error because of your property
 ( android:layout_gravity = "fill" )
actually this is used to fill the container
check out this link 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet working fine.You might be facing issues due to some other layout parameters changes in your project.

I will recommend try to create new project and check your layout again 
[image: Snapshot]